# How to SELECT from MySQL server using difference?

Tags: php, sql

Let's take a value :

```
$weight = 50
```

In database, I have 4 peoples name. Their weight is 40,50,35,54 respectively. I want to take those peoples name whose weight isn't more than `$weight+10` and less than `$weight-10`. Is there any direct way to run it in SQL? Or should I apply logic here?

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `users`");

$array = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
       if($row['weight']<$weight+10 AND $row['weight']>$weight-10){
           $name = $row['name'];
           $weight = $row['weight'];
       }
}
```

I am expecting shorter code like instead of applying logic in PHP, just call those data whose weight is not more than 60 and not less than 40

Answer (score 0):

I have found [it](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_op_between). I am not so sure if it is what I was looking for since I haven't tested. But the code tells me that it's what I was looking for.

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `weight` BETWEEN 40 AND 60
```